# Rails many-to-many same class bi-directional relationship.. how?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

So heres the deal.. i'm writing a rails application to manage contact data..

I have a contact model and that contact needs to have many family members (still the contact class).. that relationship needs associated relationship data.. ie

```
ContactA | ContactB | Relationship
1          2          Contact A is Contact B's Father
```

How can i relate 2 objects of the same class and attach some data and be able to traverse te relationship bidirectionally like so:

```
@guy1 = Contact.find(1) #Guy A
@guy1.family_relationships
>>> [[guyb, "f"], [guyc, "s"]]
@guy2 = @guy1.family_members.first
@guy1.family_members
>>> [[guya]]
```

Thats probably not 100% correct but its late and ive been battling with a server all day so please forgive me!!

I've heard you have to do all kinds of hacky SQL to do it..

Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: In a question involving models you should show their structure so we know the exact associations between them. In any case, the example you show is weird.

Comment: Hey @tokland ..it's just a simple family relationship i.e. a person has a family member, and that family member could be a sibling or a father or a mother etc. but those people are still people so they should still belong in the person model, i just wanna know how i can relate many people to each other and attach some data to the relationship.. ie they are related because he is his father.. make sense?

Comment: Quite close to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275567/how-do-you-handle-side-effect-of-duplication-when-using-joins-tables-i-e-recip/4277993#4277993) You may want to read that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the great answers but found the answer here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Railscasts is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation in one of my projects earlier. I went with the following design:

```
class Patient < AR::Base
  has_many :relatives, :dependent => :destroy do
    def husband
      select { |r| r.relation.eql?('Husband').first
    end

    def father
      select { |r| r.relation.eql?('Father').first
    end

    ... 

    def sons
      select { |r| r.relation.eql?('Son')
    end
    ...
  end
end

class Relative < AR::Base
  belongs_to :patient

  validates :relation, 
    :inclusion => { 
      :in => %w( Husband Daughter Son Father Mother Brother Sister )
    }
end
```

This works for me. Hope this helps you or at least point you in the right direction!